# hadoop and its technologies setup

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie, ambari

For study project requirement, I am selecting following technology because source of data is SQL SERVER

Initial data size is 100Gb and 10 growth@quarter

Information

Hadoop – Multi node cluster (1Namenode + 3 DataNode)
Hadoop 3.1.2,
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Ubuntu 18.04
Ambari

Above setup is ready now following item remaining

Sqoop:  1.4.7
Hive: 2.3.5
Oozie 5.0.0

Should they all be installed on separate machines?
What is the deployment strategy once development completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the hardware available, then yes, every master service should be on separate machines for fault tolerance purposes.

Meaning, Oozie server, Hive server, Hive metastore are all separate.

Sqoop and Hive client are only clients and can be on any NodeManager

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please share any link for depth understanding.

Comment: what is the deployment strategy

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You already have Ambari, right? It suggests deployment strategies itself